# Create a media gallery search engine using web technologies

Tags: php, node.js, gallery, media, koken

I have a requirement to create a media gallery with search features(advanced) , based on tags. I am primarily a front end developer but have experience with PHP, nodejs and Java as well. I am open to use any CMS and any web technology. I have looked through Koken , but we need to add sounds and videos using soundcloud/vimeo , which is not what is required , also the search feature(advanced, not just clicking on tags) will have to be worked around with not much documentation and support. What is the best way to implement it ? Using Wordpress/Drupal , or build it from scratch using own database and querying it ?

Any inputs ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: I don't why a CMS should be of any advantage here... A CMS is about offering easy and secure means to create articles and new pages in an existing page. Which is not what you want to do. I would suggest you take a look at "web frameworks" or "MVC frameworks" for this instead.

Comment: But please note that questions for recommendations are not within the scope of StackOverflow.

Comment: MVC frameworks is okay , but the media will also have to uploaded and fetched from , so the host will make a difference. I need to provide an "admin" to upload the media and add tags to the media.

Comment: Ah, that is something completely different then! In your question you wrote you want to implement a search engine. What you say here now is something different, since you want to handle the actual content, not only the search index. But even so: uploading videos and sound files is not creating articles and pages. Or should the media files be part of articles and the like? So something more like a blogging platform?

Comment: Actually I need to do everything , from creating the admin , to implementing it. No , it is not a blogging platform , just an educational resource for going through media files and searching it. [Koken](http://koken.me/) seemed to me a fine option , but I am still doubtful about search options even if I create a new theme.